# Access the textbox of dynamically created table in listview of user control page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, user-controls

I'm creating web template using asp.net and C#.
in my user control page i have to create the table dynamically inside the list view. I just read the data from XML file then retrieve the name and number of columns and rows of each table. While I'm creating the table I assign the name and id to each cell. In this dynamic table once the user click on the edit button of each row all the cells of this row will change to `textbox`. then the user can change the data of this `textboxes`,
but in my update function I cannot access to these `textboxes` by `id` and store the data in database.
Below is my dynamic table code which is created at the `ItemDataBound` function:

```
System.Data.DataRowView rowView = e.Item.DataItem as System.Data.DataRowView;
TableRow tr_DataBound = new TableRow();
TableCell tc_DataBound = new TableCell();
for (int i = 1; i <= pkCounter + nonPkCounter; i++)
            {
                //tc_DataBound = new TableCell();
                tc_DataBound = new TableCell();
                TextBox tb = new TextBox();
                //(TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("td_EditTemp" + i);
                tb.Width = 110;
                tb.Text = rowView[i - 1].ToString();
                tb.ID = "td_EditTemp" + i;
                tc_DataBound.Controls.Add(tb);
                tc_DataBound.CssClass = "th_ItemTemplate";
                tr_DataBound.Cells.Add(tc_DataBound);
            }
        tr_DataBound.Cells.Add(tc_DataBound);
        Table table_Lv_ItemTemplate = (Table)e.Item.FindControl("Table_Lv_ItemTemplate");
        table_Lv_ItemTemplate.Rows.Add(tr_DataBound);
```

My `listview` code is:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lv_Uc_Module" runat="server"
                    onitemediting="lv_Uc_Module_ItemEditing" 
                    onitemcanceling="lv_Uc_Module_ItemCanceling" 
                    onitemdeleting="lv_Uc_Module_ItemDeleting"  
                    OnItemDataBound="lv_Uc_Module_ItemDataBound"
                    OnSorting="lv_Uc_Module_Sorting">

                        <LayoutTemplate>
                            <asp:Table runat="server" ID="table_Lv_Layout">
                                <asp:TableRow runat="server" ID="tr_Table_Layout">
                                    <asp:TableCell runat="server" ID="td_Table_Layout">
                                        <asp:Table runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholderContainer">
                                            <asp:TableRow runat="server" ID="tr_Table_IphContainer">

                                                <asp:TableHeaderCell runat="server">
                                                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="th_Ph_Lv_header" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                                                </asp:TableHeaderCell>
                                            </asp:TableRow>
                                            <asp:TableRow runat="server">
                                                <asp:TableCell runat="server">

                                                    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder" />

                                                </asp:TableCell>

                                            </asp:TableRow>
                                        </asp:Table>
                                    </asp:TableCell>
                                </asp:TableRow>
                                <asp:TableRow runat="server" ID="tr_Validate_Table_Layout">
                                    <asp:TableCell runat="server" ID="td_Validate_Table_Layout" HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="#CCCCCC">
                                        <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" HeaderText="You received the following errors:" ShowMessageBox="true" ShowSummary="false" ValidationGroup="VGEditTmp" />

                                    </asp:TableCell>
                                </asp:TableRow>
                            </asp:Table>
                            <br />
                            <asp:DataPager ID="lv_DataPager" runat="server" PagedControlID="lv_Uc_Module" PageSize="25" OnPreRender="lv_DataPager_PreRender">
                                <Fields>
                                    <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Image" ShowFirstPageButton="true" ShowLastPageButton="true" FirstPageImageUrl="~/Images/First.png" LastPageImageUrl="~/Images/Last.png" NextPageImageUrl="~/Images/Next.png" PreviousPageImageUrl="~/Images/Previous.png" />
                                    <asp:TemplatePagerField>
                                        <PagerTemplate>
                                            <span style="color:Blue;">
                                            </span>
                                        </PagerTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplatePagerField>
                                </Fields>
                            </asp:DataPager>
                        </LayoutTemplate>

                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TableRow runat="server">
                                <asp:TableCell runat="server">

                                    <asp:Table runat="server" ID="Table_Lv_ItemTemplate"></asp:Table>
                                </asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:TableCell runat="server">
                                    <asp:Button ID="btn_Edit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="" CssClass="btn_Edit" CausesValidation="True" Visible="false" />
                                    <asp:Button ID="btn_Delete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="" CssClass="btn_Delete" CausesValidation="false" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?');" Visible="false" />
                                </asp:TableCell>
                            </asp:TableRow>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:ListView>
```

I'm using below method in my update function at the code behind to access the data changed at the `textbox`:

```
TextBox tb = (lv_Uc_Module.Items[e].FindControl("td_EditTemp" + i + "_" + e)) as TextBox;
```

Could you please guide me how to access these `textboxes` data.
 Appreciate your consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at using the asp:repeater?

It makes creating dynamic controls much simpler especially if you use the 'Data_Bound' Event.

Have a look here - [repeater example](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/tutorials/article.php/c12065).